# Need to export LyX doc as single file; figure files local, bib inline, and *tested*

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

The final submission process for a paper I've composed in LyX requires submission of a single `.tex` file.  I've had some success toward that goal but I still have some major gaps towards getting that all ironed out.

There are a couple of related questions on this site, which makes me wonder whether I should submit an "Export as Flat" feature request to the LyX folks, but this journal's requirements may be unusual; I don't really know.  They can be found at [1](http://tcas1.polito.it/accept.html).

So, I dug into the `.tmp` files that LyX creates (and I'm on Mac, so that's a little tricky to start with) and found some of what I wanted: a `.tex` file with all of the file names for figures collapsed to remove all directories, all of the actual figure files, and a `.bbl` file.

However, my first problem is that it's been so long since I've tried to use LaTeX directly, I'm at a loss of how to finish it all off.

One complication being that the TeX utils don't even seem to be on my path at the command prompt.  I thought that I'd be able to at least find the path to the LaTeX executable thingy in "Preferences", where it has the path for things like `dvips`, but alas I'm still stuck.

I'm sure that the `.bbl` file gets turned into `.tex` and some point, but I haven't been able to find such a thing among the `.tmp` files produced by LyX, or figure out/remember how that part of it works.

And I feel like to need to be able to do the `tex2dvi` thing on the files once I've got them ready for submission, so that I can make sure it all still works like it did in LyX to produce the PDF.

And I thought that I would see the commands used in the `.log` file.  But in there I could only see the *output* from those commands, and not the actual commands used (maybe that should be a LyX feature request, too).

Anyway, any insight that a LyX veteran could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From within LyX File->Export->as LaTeX. It makes sense to export it into the current directory of the LyX file. Then run the file from the terminal window:

```
pdflatex <file>
bibtex <file>
pdflatex <file>
pdflatex <file>
```

This is what LyX does for you if running the LyX doc. 
That should create the files .pdf and also .bbl

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the compilation isn't even necessary as he or she needs to submit a .tex file (which is a bit odd). In case there are other files needed to be included (e.g. a bibliography), the [filecontents](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package might be of help.

Comment: @doncherry: The tex-file is already there, but not the bbl, if you are not in the temporary directory of LyX. And that bbl is created with my sequence

Comment: The reason why I didn't use the File->Export->LaTeX is that it retains a full path to the figure files, whereas the .tex file that I found in the tmp directory had not only copied all of the necessary figures into that same directory but also updated the filename for the figures in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I just replaced the lines that read `\bibliographystyle{...}
\bibliography{...}` with the contents of the `.bbl` file, then that satisfied the requirement that the bibliography be contained within the tex file (no separate `.bib` files were allowed).